# sending data from script to .cs page

Tags: asp.net

i am getting values from .cs to script but i want to send data from script to .cs page
i have tried this,but it is not working.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
         $(document).ready(function() {
         $("hfServerValue").val("From ClientSide!");
         });
     </script>

   <asp:HiddenField ID="hfServerValue" runat="server" />

 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       Response.Write(hfServerValue.Value.ToString ());      
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't directly invoke the Page_Load method from script. There are several ways to send data to server.
Try using an XMLHttpReqest

- http://www.jibbering.com/2002/4/httprequest.html
- http://www.openjs.com/articles/ajax_xmlhttp_using_post.php

If you're using jQuery, you may also try [$.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/), [$.load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/) etc.

Do remember that unlike a submit action which internally creates a request, you're trying to create the request yourself so you might need to deal with stuff like request headers (content-type, content-length etc.), content etc. So, there's a bit of work to do here even though you're trying to do a simple thing. But once you get it running it comes naturally.

Answer (score 1):

You first need to add a control that get the data from javascript and post them back:

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="hfServerValue" runat="server" />
```

Then you place data on that control by getting the cliendID.

```
$(document).ready(function() { $("<%=hfServerValue.ClientID%>").val("From ClientSide!"); });
```

And then on post back you get them

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
    if(IsPostBack)
    {
        var YourReturn = hfServerValue.Text;

    }   
}
```

This is an answer to a question. Of course ajax is a different way.

### Update

Now I see the hidden field, this is also a better way the hidden field. The only error is that you did not use the **CliendID** !. Also I do not know if you use prototype or jquery or just microsoft.

Comment: @nitin Yes its works, search for javascript errors that stop javascript from run. Also this works on postback !.

Comment: i did not get what is 'divNotice' in "<%=divNotice.ClientID%>".

Comment: why i am getting error for  style="display:hidden" and hfServerValue.Text

Comment: @nitin I have update my answer, please see it again. The divNotice was from a previous code, I change it to hfServerValue. Please note that you need to get the clientID on the render code. Search to see what is